# Как правильно читать документацию?

Tags: php

Меня интересует, как читать доку, допустим, на php.net , как её правильно переводить. Может, какие-то подводные камни есть именно в переводе на русский да и вообще.

Comment: Читать, как справочник, руководствуясь в первую очередь формальной логикой, во вторую - здравым смыслом. Непонятен вопрос, русский перевод там не самый плохой, кстати, если что-то непонятно, смотрите комменты (внимание - комменты не модерируются почти - регуляция сообществом чтецов доки, но полезные примеры там можно найти (смотрите на количество голосов "за")). Могу для примера показать, какие мысли у меня в голове, когда я читаю статью какую-нибудь, дайте ссылку на то, что вам кажется непонятным, и мы объясним, как подобное понимать.

Comment: @msim, на php.net довольно внятный перевод на русский, я бы за него не волновался. Просто обращайте внимание на всё написанное (статья в документации, как правило, - короткая выжимка функционала без описания внутренних процессов). И не стесняйтесь заглядывать в заплюсованные комментарии - там, как правило, есть примеры/объяснения самых частых use-case'ов.

Comment: мда, hivemind